# How to install i686-elf compiler?

Tags: software-installation, 22.04, gcc, cross-compilation

I'm starting out writing a (very basic) operating system, using [the Osdev wiki](https://wiki.osdev.org). It recommends that I use the `i686-elf` toolchain, but I've had trouble installing it on my system. I'm running **Ubuntu 22.04**. I've tried [this git repository](https://github.com/lordmilko/i686-elf-tools), but there were various issues, such as having to change all occurrences `python` to `python3` in the `i686-elf-tools.sh` file, and `mxe` never being able to successfully build.

Has anybody else managed to get this working?

**Edit:**

Here's the error it threw:

```
Failed to build package mxe-conf for target i686-w64-mingw32.static!
------------------------------------------------------------
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
python --version
bash: line 1: python: command not found
make[1]: *** [Makefile:889: build-only-mxe-conf_i686-w64-mingw32.static] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory '/opt/mxe'
real    0m1.880s
user    0m1.838s
sys 0m0.050s
------------------------------------------------------------
[log]      /opt/mxe/log/mxe-conf_i686-w64-mingw32.static

make: *** [Makefile:888: /opt/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/installed/mxe-conf] Error 1
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about the errors you are encountering? The `gcc` target of mxe (cloned from https://github.com/mxe/mxe.git) appeared to build OK on a 22.04 VM after changing python to python3 (or installing the python-is-python3 package) and installing a couple of prerequisites (most notably `libtool-bin`, which doesn't seem to be mentioned in the documentation).

Comment: @steeldriver I edited my post to include the error message.

Comment: Thanks - so that seems to be the same issue you already encountered in the i686-elf-tools.sh script, i.e. that current versions of Ubuntu do not provide the ambiguous `python` by default. You can either edit the mxe Makefile to refer to `python3` explicitly, or (probably simpler) at least temporarily install the `python-is-python3` package. If (possible given the age of the software) there is some python2-specific syntax, you may need to backtrack and install python2.7 instead (but that doesn't seem to be the case for mxe at least).